# Lotus Notes: get parent category name for column formula

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, categories, lotus-formula

In my Lotus Notes database, I have a view that shows some documents, categorized by date. Date field may have several dates in it, so I use @Explode(Date) to show documents in all categories it can be in.

But in one of the columns I need to show info based on the category the row is. Is it possible? I.e. how do I get, in a column view, the name of a row's parent category?

I've tried using the programmatic name of a categorized column, but, in a situation when multiple values are there, using the programmatic name of a column shows all the values, not the "current" one.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the name of the categorized column but you have to set following properties for this column:[image]

It's important that it is not sorted and has marked "multiple values as separate entries".

EDIT:

It does work only for views with **one** category.

If you have the need to categorize more then one value then you have to concatenate them with "\" in one categorized column.

Example:

Given a document with multivalue fields

```
Field A: aaa, bbb, ccc
Field B: 111, 222
```

you would use a formula for categorized column

```
(A + "\\") *+ B
```

and name the categorized column in last property tab "column1"

[image]

put then the value "column1" in the unsorted multivalue column

[image]

then you'll get this view as result

[image]

You are then free to manipulate the value in second column with formula.

Comment: "It's important that it is not sorted and has marked "multiple values as separate entries"." - this way I just won't get the categorized column at all. If you switch off the "Sort", "Type" is automatically set to "Standard", while I need the column to be categorized.

Comment: These settings aren't for categories column but for column where you want to use the content of categoriesed column

Comment: Ah, sorry - understood now. I'll try this shortly.

Comment: Nope, didn't help. See: http://tinypic.com/r/dbl5xd/5 - here the last column directly refers the 1st (categorized) column by programmatic name. Using your settings, it just shows the very 1st value, not the value of a parent column.

Comment: This didn't help either: http://tinypic.com/r/2vio31i/5 - removing the 2nd categorized term gives the same result.

Comment: However - removing all other columns & simplifying the view to the bones did work! Maybe some issues with sorting, etc. Anyway, I'll accept your answer, thanks!

Comment: One more question, though: it seems that the "column1" value that is used in column calculations is a text list that contains all multi-values of categorized column (though it shows the correct value when output to a column). Any way I can extract the actual value from it? Strange behavior.

Comment: In the end, it seems that it's impossible to use the "column1" for calculations - only for output. Bad luck.

Comment: You can do calculations but you have to deal with a list. All operations you do in formula have to work for the list. At the end you have to have the same amount of listmembers. For my example you could take the number and add 1: @ToNumber(@Right(column1; "\\")) + 1